# IndexOutOfBoundsException in ArrayList when unchecking checkbox android

Tags: android, arraylist, expandablelistview, indexoutofboundsexception, expandablelistadapter

In `ExpandableListview` I am using `checkbox` with `Imageview` in `childview`

For managing the state of `checkbox` dues to its recycling property I used ArrayList

I am not able to get where the mistake is happening , 
Pls help me in this case

Thanks in Advance

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);  
        Log.e("_childText", "karjeevch "+childText);


        int itemType = getChildType(groupPosition,childPosition);      


        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        switch (itemType) {

        case 0:
            viewHolder = null;
            convertView=null;
            if (convertView==null) {

                viewHolder=new ViewHolder();                
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_shape, null);
                viewHolder.shape_name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
                //viewHolder.shape_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
                viewHolder.img_shape_icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_shape);                


                imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://rosycontact.com/shashvat/images/"+childText.toLowerCase()+".png", viewHolder.img_shape_icon);                
                Log.e("shape", "karjeevshp "+childText);
                viewHolder.shape_name.setText(childText);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);               


               //final TextView shape_name_temp=viewHolder.shape_name;

               viewHolder.shape_name.setChecked(itemChecked.get(childPosition));
               final CheckBox shape_name_temp=viewHolder.shape_name;
              viewHolder.shape_name.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        int id=buttonView.getId();


                        if (id==R.id.shape_chk_box) {

                            if (shape_name_temp.isChecked()==true) {

                                String shape_str=shape_name_temp.getText().toString();
                                All_link.SHAPE_LIST.add(shape_str);
                                Toast.makeText(_context, shape_name_temp.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.e("chk_shape", "karjeevch "+shape_name_temp.getText().toString());                              
                            }
                            else{
                                String shape_str=shape_name_temp.getText().toString();
                                All_link.SHAPE_LIST.remove(shape_str);                                                          }
                        }                                                                                           
                    }
                });  

               viewHolder.shape_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(position_of_click.contains (childPosition)){ 
                        position_of_click.remove(childPosition);
                    } 
                    else{ 
                        position_of_click.add(childPosition);
                    }
                }
            });



               if(position_of_click.contains(childPosition)){ 
                   viewHolder.shape_name.setChecked(true);
                }
               else{ 
                   viewHolder.shape_name.setChecked(false);
            }

            }
            else{
                //viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://rosycontact.com/shashvat/images/"+childText.toLowerCase()+".png", viewHolder.img_shape_icon);                                             
                viewHolder.shape_name.setText(childText);                               
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);                             
            }
            return convertView;
```

I am getting IndexOutOfBoundsException at line `position_of_click.remove(childPosition);` when I uncheck the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `position_of_click` variable is an `ArrayList<Integer>` object ?

In this case, take care with the `remove()` method : you want to use `remove(Object object)` and you are using `remove(int index)`. To force your code to use the `remove(Object object)` method, you must cast your argument like :

```
position_of_click.remove((Integer)childPosition);
```

Comment: Mmh ok sorry, so you can use : int index = position_of_click.indexOf(childPosition); 
position_of_click.remove(index);

But take care, with this method you will remove only the first occurence of your childPosition value, but I think it's a unique value in your Array ? If not : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740701/how-to-remove-particular-data-from-arraylistinteger-in-android